# Tensorflow map function split the dataset structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am having a trouble with the structure of the dataset in the tensorflow map function.
This is how my data looks like :

simple

```
`train_examples = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,...],
 [32,33,34,35,36,...]],
```

real

```
print(train_data[0])
[[array([2,539, 400, 513, 398, 523, 485, 533, 568, 566, 402, 565, 491,
   570, 576, 539, 351, 538, 297, 539, 262, 564, 313, 581, 370, 589,
   421, 514, 314, 501, 370, 489, 420,3]), array([2, 534, 403, 507, 401, 519, 487, 531, 567, 562, 405, 544, 495,
   537, 588, 528, 354, 526, 300, 534, 259, 555, 315, 575, 370, 589,
   421, 499, 315, 489, 372, 483, 423,3])]]
```

I convert to tensor for the pipeline `<TensorSliceDataset shapes: (2, 34), types: tf.int64>`

The train_examples contains 2D tensors, [[source],[target]] with 17k rows.

```
def make_batches(ds):
    return (
        ds
        .cache()
        .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        .map(lambda x_int,y_int: x_int,y_int, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

train_batches = make_batches(train_examples)
```

for the map, I want the data structure output with source and target separately. I tried with the function `map(prepare, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)`

```
def prepare(ds):
  srcs = tf.ragged.constant(ds.numpy().[0],tf.int64)
  trgs = tf.ragged.constant(ds.numpy().[1],tf.int64)

  srcs = srcs.to_tensor()
  trgs = trgs.to_tensor()
  return srcs,trgs
```

But the tensorflow doesn't allow the eager execution in the map function.
If there is other thing I missed about the usage of map function in Tensorflow, please let me know. Thank you.

Tensorflow version = 2.7

Comment: Can you provide a full example of what your data looks like?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited for the full example of what the data looks like. Thank you

Comment: Ok so each sample is made up of two arrays with the shape `(34,)` each?

Comment: yes, the data structure contains 2 arrays with the shape of (34,) each.

Comment: I want to return the data of that (34,) and another (34,). Right now the data is in one bracket of tensor (2,34). Just like the return in `def prepare(ds)`

Comment: the `train_data` is an interpretaion from the csv file of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try splitting your samples like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


data = [[np.array([2,539, 400, 513, 398, 523, 485, 533, 568, 566, 402, 565, 491,
   570, 576, 539, 351, 538, 297, 539, 262, 564, 313, 581, 370, 589,
   421, 514, 314, 501, 370, 489, 420,3]), np.array([2, 534, 403, 507, 401, 519, 487, 531, 567, 562, 405, 544, 495,
   537, 588, 528, 354, 526, 300, 534, 259, 555, 315, 575, 370, 589,
   421, 499, 315, 489, 372, 483, 423,3])]]

samples = 50
data = data * samples
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)

def prepare(x):
  srcs, trgs = tf.split(x, num_or_size_splits = 2, axis=1)
  return srcs,trgs

def make_batches(ds):
    return (
        ds
        .cache()
        .shuffle(50)
        .batch(10)
        .map(prepare, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

train_batches = make_batches(ds)
for x, y in train_batches.take(1):
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

```
(10, 1, 34) (10, 1, 34)
```